# SonarQube with Sonar-runner cannot store report

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have SonarQube 5.1 installed with sonar-runner 2.4, using Oracle database. When running sonar-runner on my project the analysis goes well and all steps until publishing the report is without problem, but then the logger gives me this:

```
08:04:45.705 INFO  - Sensor JavaSquidSensor (done) | time=147026ms
08:04:45.705 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor
08:04:46.007 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=302ms
08:04:46.008 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor
08:04:46.016 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor (done) | time=8ms
08:04:46.017 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor
08:04:46.363 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor (done) | time=346ms
08:04:46.364 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor
08:04:46.474 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor (done) | time=110ms
08:04:46.475 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor
08:04:46.908 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor (done) | time=433ms
08:04:46.909 INFO  - Sensor SurefireSensor
08:04:46.911 INFO  - parsing /app/aim/jenkinsNew/jobs/Unit Testing with Code Coverage (DEV)/workspace/download/Omegapoint/.sonar/build/surefire-reports
08:04:46.911 WARN  - Reports path not found: /app/aim/jenkinsNew/jobs/Unit Testing with Code Coverage (DEV)/workspace/download/Omegapoint/.sonar/build/surefire-reports
08:04:46.912 INFO  - Sensor SurefireSensor (done) | time=3ms
08:04:46.912 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor
08:04:46.912 INFO  - No SCM system was detected. You can use the 'sonar.scm.provider' property to explicitly specify it. 
08:04:46.912 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=0ms
08:04:46.912 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor
08:04:46.912 INFO  - JavaCpdEngine is used for java
08:04:46.915 INFO  - Cross-project analysis disabled
08:04:53.913 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor (done) | time=7001ms
08:04:53.917 INFO  - No quality gate is configured.
08:04:55.523 INFO  - Execute decorators...
08:05:13.250 INFO  - Store results in database
08:05:39.050 INFO  - Analysis reports generated in 2135ms, dir size=1 MB
08:05:42.067 INFO  - Analysis reports compressed in 3016ms, zip size=927 KB
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 4:09.242s
Final Memory: 26M/230M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: Fail to execute request [code=500, url=http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9010/api/computation/submit_report?projectKey=SonarCube-report]: {"errors":[{"msg":"Fail to store analysis report of project SonarCube-report"}]}
ERROR: 
ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run SonarQube Runner with the -e switch.
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

The server SonarQube log sonar.log gives a long output (truncated here):

```
2015.06.05 08:58:41 ERROR web[o.s.s.w.WebServiceEngine] Fail to process request http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9010/api/computation/submit_report?projectKey=SonarCube-report
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to store analysis report of project SonarCube-report
    at org.sonar.server.computation.ReportQueue.add(ReportQueue.java:67) ~[sonar-server-5.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.ws.SubmitReportWsAction.handle(SubmitReportWsAction.java:75) ~[sonar-server-5.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceEngine.execute(WebServiceEngine.java:84) ~[sonar-server-5.1.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620) ~[na:2.6 (12-15-2014)]
```

and

```
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1157) [na:1.7.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:627) [na:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:863) [na:1.7.0]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: not opened for reading
    at org.jruby.util.io.ChannelStream.checkReadable(ChannelStream.java:134) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.util.io.ChannelStream.bufferedRead(ChannelStream.java:994) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.util.io.ChannelStream.access$300(ChannelStream.java:62) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.util.io.ChannelStream$InputStreamAdapter.read(ChannelStream.java:1570) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:114) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1792) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1769) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1744) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(FileUtils.java:1512) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.ReportQueue.saveReportOnDisk(ReportQueue.java:88) ~[sonar-server-5.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.ReportQueue.add(ReportQueue.java:61) ~[sonar-server-5.1.jar:na]
    ... 357 common frames omitted
```

I have double-checked that the database contains all sonar tables and data, and that it is reachable. Since I get this far in the process I suppose that connecting to the database is not problem? Any suggestions what to do?

Comment: Could you please provide server logs ?

Comment: I added server output in my question. It is a huge stacktrace for the first error (fail to process..), a few hundred lines.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment (need more "reputation" on stackoverflow) here's what I'm thinking:

First, I believe you're right that it isn't a database issue.  This seems to be an issue with the server gathering the stored data.

So to resolve this, please check these things:

1. Check that your server's port 9010 is open/free while your sonar analysis is running.
2. Check your sonar.properties file for how you've configured the web server.
3. Check your wrapper.conf file
4. Check your access.log

Let me know what you find.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on SonarQube server. Root cause was iNode count. SonarQube  dir had couple of million files under its tmp directory. I deleted all the files under this tmp to free up inodes & did a restart. inode count (df -ih) then looked normal and SQ started working just fine.